# How to include a jsp using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to include a jsp in another jsp when I click a button.Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

My code:
I have logout code button. On clicking it I need to show a confirmation page.

```
<s:form name="LogoutAction"
                id="LogoutAction" action="logout">
    <span class="inlayField2">
    <s:a href="logout" cssClass="planTabHeader" id="logoutId"> <img src="../../KY/images/common/header/lock.png" alt="logout" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;" /> &nbsp;Log out</s:a></span>
    </s:form> 

$('#logoutId').click(function(event) {

    $('#logoutdiv').load('ConfirmationPopup.jsp');
});
```