# Include a jsp inside another when a button is clicked

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a logout button.Once it is clicked, I want to show a page confirmlogout.jsp and then based on the user's response, the user has to logout or stay there.

My code:

```
<span class="inlayField2">
    <s:a href="#" cssClass="planTabHeader" id="logoutId"> <img src="../../KY/images/common/header/lock.png" alt="logout" style="border: none;background-color: transparent;" /> &nbsp;Log out</s:a></span>
    </s:form>

<div id="confirmPopup" style="display:none;">
      <%@ include file="/planmanagement/planSummary/ConfirmationPopup.jsp" %>
    </div>


$('#logoutId').click(function(event) {
$('#confirmPopup').css('display','block');
});
```

My problem is when the page containing the logout is loaded, the confirmationpopup.jsp is displayed eventhough I have set display:none. And when I click the logout,confirmationpopup is not showing up.Please help me solve this.thanks in advance

Comment: It's the third time you ask this same question today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162450/how-to-include-a-jsp-inside-another-jsp-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163287/how-to-include-a-jsp-using-javascript

Comment: Check if your html is well-formed. style attribute may not be applied on the div due to a malformed html.

Comment: @WilQu : yes because at every time I am getting the answer from different people. And I will ask till I get the solution

Comment: Maybe you can check in firebug; right click the element and choose inpect element. See if display property of the element is set to none. The code as far as you posted it should be fine but if the confirm is visible then either your html is invalid or another script sets it visible.

Answer (score 1):

Could you confirm that the event handler is called and that the right element is set visible?

You can see console messages in firefox (preferable with firebug) or chrome when pressing F12

```
$('#logoutId').click(function(event) {
  console.log("logout clicked");
  console.log("showing element:",$('#confirmPopup'));
  $('#confirmPopup').show();
});
```

Comment: As per the question, the jsp is also visible when the page is viewed. So that is the first problem.

Comment: event handler is called...My question is I am getting the confirmationpopup when the page is loaded and not when the logout is clicked

Comment: @Ankit : I am setting the display:none. Even then how it is displayed

Comment: @mukund:Check if your html is well-formed. style attribute may not be applied on the div due to a malformed html.

Answer (score -1):

You might try this:

```
<div id="confirmPopup" style="display:none;">
<script>
    $('#confirmPopup').click(function(){
    document.write('<%@ include file="/planmanagement/planSummary/ConfirmationPopup.jsp" %>');
    }
</script>
 </div>
```

Comment: but why $('#confirmPopup').click...I am not clicking it

Comment: <%@ include file is server side code, writing that in javascript will not include the jsp on page.

Comment: @mukund you are right, registring click on confirmPopup isn't right, I missed logout button clicked description of yours. Ankit: yes since he wants to execute server side code when div is shown, document.write at the place you what to run server-side code is necessary. This is typical JSP/JS style code.

Comment: @harsh: Document.write will just write that string as string only. and not as jsp code.

Comment: So what is the solution for this?